# Share data in electron via typescript

Tags: typescript, electron

https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages

How do I accomplish the global variable:

```
// In the main process.
global.sharedObject = {
  someProperty: 'default value'
}
```

If my electron-main is typescript?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you just looking to type assert to Global so you don't get compiler errors? (or merge the someProperty property with the Global typings via some global.d.ts file)

Comment: I've tried `declare`ing the object as described in typescript, or various other methods, but I can never access the object as described in the FAQ. I simply can't ant to reproduce the FAQ logic in a typescript electron main.

Comment: at point in the following code are you breaking? `require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').someProperty = 'new value'`

Comment: for typescript `global['name'] = value` worked.